# Matlab recursion

Tags: matlab, recursion

Need a little help understanding what is happening in this function particularly line 7 `[Fnm1,Fnm2] = fibrecurmemo(N-1);` I don't understand how a new variable can be declared here with in the array. an example of what is happening would be appreciated.

```
function [Fn,Fnm1] = fibrecurmemo(N)
% Computes the Fibonacci number, F(N), using a memoized recursion
if N <= 2
  Fn = 1;
  Fnm1 = 1;
else
  [Fnm1,Fnm2] = fibrecurmemo(N-1);
  Fn = Fnm1 + Fnm2;
end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Say we start with:

```
fibrecurmemo(3) %// N is 3
```

The `else` statements run (since `N > 2`):

```
[Fnm1,Fnm2] = fibrecurmemo(2); %//statement 1
Fn = Fnm1 + Fnm2; %//statement 2
```

Before `statement 2` can run, `fibrecurmemo(2)` must first run.

---

The `if` statements in `fibrecurmemo(2)` run (since `N <= 2`):

```
Fn = 1;
Fnm1 = 1;
```

As a result, `fibrecurmemo(2)` returns `1, 1`.

---

Contininuing from `statement 1` above,

```
[1,1] = fibrecurmemo(2); %//statement 1
Fn = 1 + 1; %//statement 2
```

Finally,

```
[2, 1] = fibrecurmemo(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function returns two values.

```
function [xFive,yFive] = addFive(x,y)
  xFive = x + 5;
  yFive = y + 5;
end

xx = (addFive(3,4))
```

xx will be equal to 8 in this example

the syntax for assignment for multiple return values is 
     [a,b,c,...]  = someFunc();

where someFunc() has output of [a,b,c,...]

```
[aa,bb] = addFive(3,4);
cc = addFive(3,4);
```

if you do it this way you would get

aa == 8

bb == 9

cc == 8

in the case of cc instead of [aa,bb] Then you will just get the first return value.

i.e. you could do

```
x = fibrecurmemo(5)
[y,z] = fibrecurmemo(5)

in this case x == y
```